# Rendering the nbsp issue of the XML in the JS

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

This is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_xml_content_string() 
{
                        xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        xmldoc.async = false;
                        xmldoc.load("book.xml");
                        xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                         xsldoc.async = false;
                         xsldoc.load("try.xsl");
                         ex= xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
                         document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = ex;

}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="load_xml_content_string()">click me</button>
<div id="mytext">

</div>
```

in this HTML I'm loading the XML file and transforming that XML file using the XSLT that is below.

This is my XML:

```
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 36pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Hello rakesh</P>
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 36pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp; rakesh</P>
```

This is my XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="P">
     <xsl:variable name="check">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-SIZE:'), 'pt'))" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="round($check=8) or round($check=7) or round($check=6)">
                    <font size="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
                    </font>
          </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <font size="3">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
                    </font>
          </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my XSLT in which XML transformation is done

I want to render the `&nbsp` which is used in the `XML`.
due to that `&nbsp` my whole XML can't be loaded by the JS. I used in the HTML
so is there any method to do this..

Comment: Your XML is not valid. It cannot contain more than one root elements. Try to wrap your `<P>` elements with something around. Like `<div><P>...</P><P>...</P></div>`.

Answer (score 2):

**`&nbsp;`** is not a predefined entity in XML so usually the parsing will fail. Use **`&#xA0;`** instead.

Comment: @Molle actually this XML is given to us and they have `&nbsp` in their code and its not possible for them to replace all files...
is it possible to replace that &nbsp  using JS if yes how...help me

Comment: @Librak - What you are being sent is **not** XML. It's as simple as that. Either the data is fixed at source, or you will have to (pre-)process it as a string and fix it up, before you can treat it as XML.

Comment: so @alohci can u please help me to pre process it as a string...
i got stuck with this problem

Comment: @Librak: In case the entity is the only problem, a simple fix is to prepend: `<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">
]>
` at the start of the text of the XML -- of course in the given example you have at least one other problem -- a well-formed XML document must have a single top element -- it would be natural to wrap the presented fragment into an `<html>` top element.